# Python Not Creating Excel File with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, optimization, xlsxwriter

I have an Excel file with items and descriptions and I'm trying to compare descriptions for similarity, and if they're similar, put them in a new Excel file. Those items also have Catalog #'s and I'm comparing them to see if they're nothing like each other and they're from the same vendor (buy_line) put them also on the new Excel file. When I run the file, it takes way too long and after I leave it running, I come back and Spyder is closed and no new file. So this is a 2 part question, is there a way to make the code faster? and why is there no file created? Thank you in advance. My code is below

```
`import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

AllItems = xlrd.open_workbook('2-18All_Items-CleanUp.xlsx','rb')
sheets = AllItems.sheet_names()
item = []
base = []
kit = []
buy_line = []
catalogs = []
descriptions = []
similar_desc_item = []
similar_desc = []
diff_catalog_samebuyline = []
sh = AllItems.sheet_by_index(0)

def readexcelfunc():
    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
        item.append((row_values[0]))
        base.append((row_values[1]))
        kit.append((row_values[2]))
        buy_line.append((row_values[6]))
        catalogs.append((row_values[8]))
        descriptions.append((row_values[12]))

def check_similar_desc():
    for i,k in enumerate(descriptions):
        for j,l in enumerate(descriptions):
            ratio1 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(k,l)
            if ratio1 > 95 and k != l and base[i] != base[j] and kit[i] == "No":
                similar_desc_item.append(item[i])

def check_notmatching_catalog():
    for x,a in enumerate(catalogs):
        for y,b in enumerate(catalogs):
            ratio2 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(a,b)
            if ratio2 < 10 and buy_line[x] == buy_line[y]:
                diff_catalog_samebuyline.append(catalogs[x])

def Create_ExcelFile():
    NewWorkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sim_Desc.xlsx')
    worksheet = NewWorkbook.add_worksheet()
    row1 = 0
    row2 = 0
    for items in similar_desc_item:
        worksheet.write(row1,0,items)
        row1 += 1
    for catalognumb in diff_catalog_samebuyline:
        worksheet.write(row2,3,catalognumb)
        NewWorkbook.save()
        NewWorkbook.close()

readexcelfunc()
check_similar_desc()
print (similar_desc_item)
check_notmatching_catalog()
Create_ExcelFile()

print("Finished")`
```

Comment: why did you comment this `#Create_ExcelFile()` line. This function call writes the file right?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes, this is not normally commented out. When I pasted this code I was testing something else. I edited. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in the `Create_ExcelFile()` function. The first is that there is no workbook `save()` method. Also you aren't incrementing row2, so the second `write()` will alway write to the first row, and overwrite whatever else is there. However, most importantly, the `close()` method is at the wrong level so you are closing the file too early. Something like this should work:

```
def Create_ExcelFile():
    NewWorkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sim_Desc.xlsx')
    worksheet = NewWorkbook.add_worksheet()

    row1 = 0
    row2 = 0

    for items in similar_desc_item:
        worksheet.write(row1,0,items)
        row1 += 1

    for catalognumb in diff_catalog_samebuyline:
        worksheet.write(row2,3,catalognumb)
        # Fix the row2 increment!!

    NewWorkbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad you caught that row increment issue, it would've been really frustrating had I got it to work and only have one value. And the .close() at the wrong level solved the no file created issue. Now I'll just let it run while I do other things. Thanks again.